# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'" While trying to Instantiate an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a section of a Unity game where balloons will spawn within the bounds of a box collider. This is done randomly. However, I am having trouble Instantiating the prefab. I have tried two methods, with the same error being thrown for both.

This is the first method, here I used `GameObject.transform`.

```
for(int i = 0; i > numBalloons; i++){
            float randomX = Random.Range(left, right);
            float randomY = Random.Range(up, down);

            balloons[i] = Instantiate(BalloonPrefab, BalloonPrefab.transform);
        }
```

This was the second method, where I used a `Vector2` and `Quaternion` to try and initialize the object:

```
for(int i = 0; i > numBalloons; i++){
            float randomX = Random.Range(left, right);
            float randomY = Random.Range(up, down);

            Vector2 temp = new Vector2(randomX, randomY);

            balloons[i] = Instantiate(BalloonPrefab, temp, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

For both methods, I get the following error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'`. This is confusing me beyond belief, because if I make `BalloonPrefab` a Vector2 (which didn't seem to be a solution but was a worthy test), it asks for an object, and if I make it an object, it seems to want a Vector2. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Not enough context given, please show the declaration of the balloons array.

Comment: That actually answered my question! I accidently made the balloons array an array of Vector2's, my bad. Thankyou so much!

Comment: That's what I suspected! No problem!

Answer (score 0):

I Think your For condition is also wrong
and array think so

```
public GameObject BalloonPrefab,ballon_parent;

public GameObject[] balloons;

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numBalloons; i++)
    {
        float randomX = Random.Range(left, right);
        float randomY = Random.Range(up, down);

        Instantiate(BalloonPrefab, new Vector2(randomX, randomY),Quaternion.identity, ballon_parent.transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: put your left,right,up,down value as per your areay of spawn ballon.